Wrong comparing double column to string in MySQL
SELECT t.id, t.status, t.charges
FROM parcel AS t
WHERE t.user_id = 1
    AND t.status = 'delivered'
    AND t.charges = 'some string'
ORDER BY t.id DESC

i have this mysql query. it returns some result, but it should not. Because charges column is double and cant be equal to string

MySQL automatically converts types when comparing columns with different types.

and if either argument to a comparison operator is numeric, the other is cast to numeric, so your 'some string' becomes 0, while '123 some string' becomes 123, etc

To answer the question

it returns some result, but it should not. Because charges column is
double and cant be equal to string

From Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation

When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts strings to
numbers as necessary, and vice versa.
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
        -> 2
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(2,' test');
        -> '2 test'


See example
